# What are some good UX web designs for selecting multiple items and performing an action

Tags: user-interface, material-design, user-experience

I'm working on redesigning a web interface to provide the same functionality it has currently but with easier use via good UX design. Currently, here is what the design looks like:

[image: Current Design]

I'm less worried about the tofu look and feel, that can come later, I want to nail the UX functionality first. The idea here in this tab is the user can select the items via a checkbox and perform the actions in the "I Want To" drop down (which opens different modal dialogs depending on the action). The 3 dot ellipsis on the right of the items in the list allow the user to perform the same actions via another drop down control, with the idea that they use the top drop down to perform the actions on multiple items, the ellipsis three dot menu for one item.

The obnoxious part of this control is that the list could contain hundreds of items, and the check box takes too much precision to check quickly. The user would select which items they would like to perform the actions on sequentially, then have to scroll up to the top of the page to select the action. This could be 5 seconds of scrolling, which I find obnoxious. I want to develop a good UX pattern to provide the same functionality in less clicks, scrolling, and frustration.

My inital idea was to provide a floating action button. The user could then * somehow * (I haven't thought of an idea yet, at minimum at least a bigger check box) select multiple items then pick what they want to do via the floating action button which is always within the bounds of the screen instead of the horrible scroll back to the top (I don't think a "scroll to top" button is a good solution for this either).

So I need some recommendations on a UX pattern or some general suggestions on how to make this process less frustrating for users. I'm a fan of material design right now, but I'm open to any suggestions, material design guides don't seem to have any paradigms for something like this.

Comment: Just a remark to help sorting it out: *pagination* (as an idea) reduces clarity even further if it comes to selecting multiple items IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think the UX steps are in a good track: first select them, then set the action.

Instead of it being only a checkbox to click, the whole top part of each line could be clickable to select the item. This would make it much easier for the user, and less frustrating not being able to hit the checkbox.

Fixing the header on top would be usefull for adding a "Select/Unselect all" option and having the actions always available. Adding a searchbox to filter could be as well a good option if you are thinking of long lists. Combining the search box and the "Select all" option should help the user in their tasks.

If that is the most important action to be done in that screen, making the "What to do" button stand out a bit more would be a good idea to differenciate the primary from the secondary options for the user to do.

Answer (score 0):

I see two simple things you can do to make this more usable with very little effort.

1. Remove the checkbox and make the entire row tappable, highlighting those selected. Each row would essentially become the checkbox's label, and the checkbox itself would be hidden from view.
2. [Fix the header](http://cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/) to the top of the browser window when the user scrolls down.